# MongoDB regex case insensitive search query taking too long

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, performance, search

Hello Stack overflow community I have a search api which queries mongo to make a case insensitive regex search query .
It takes around 10 second to get results from 9 million records , but if i remove case insensitivity it is blazing fast . Can any one help me  improve performance with case insensitive search in mongo. I am using spring boot mongotemplate to query the mongo database.

Thanks

Comment: How do you query mongo? Can you post the example code?

Comment: Hello , I use spring boot mongo template to query , For example "studentName" : { "$regularExpression" : { "pattern" : "John.*", "options" : "i"}

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB regex case insensitive queries will usually not use an index. That means they will need to read every document in the collection, which is usually quite slow for non-trivial data sets.

Comment: Hey @Joe , Thanks for the response. I tried to use case insensitive indexes. but nothing helps. Can you think of any workaround for making my search query faster . Thanks.

Comment: Did you try collation?